# My Apple MacBook hard drive crashed - provisioning profiles lost, is there a way I can still update my app?

Tags: ios

My provision profiles where not backed up. The hard drive crashed and all the information, including the provision profiles was lost. Is there a way I can still update my apps on the iTunes store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new certificate if needed then create a new set of provisioning profiles. Install the updated profiles and update your apps to use the new profiles. That's it. Not that big of deal other than spending 30 minutes redoing this stuff.

Comment: Yep. It's tedious, but I've done it quite a few times, most often when I forget to export my previous profiles from Xcode before wiping/reinstalling an OS.

Comment: @craig Then use Xcode to handle the provisioning profiles.... if you go into Organizer and do it from their.

Comment: Hi,I'm a little confuse.  I thought after a app was submitted, the updates of the app all had to have the same provision profile?????

Comment: Not all. The only requirement of an app update is that the app's bundle id is the same. New provisioning profiles get created  for apps all of the time. It will work.